Embed Windows Terminal into WPF application
Is it somehow possible to embed a Windows Terminal Window (https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) inside a C# WPF Applikation?
I would like to make use of the VT100 capability of the new Windows Terminal Window, but embedded within my WPF Applikation.

There has been a feature request going on but it may not be  fully usable WPF Control yet.

Thank you for mentioning that, seems to be quite old, and as you say, not fully usable.
I have found the https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/main/src/cascadia/WpfTerminalControl which seems to be what I want to achive, I am able to open the UserControl "TerminalControl", but I don't know, how I am able to interact with this Control? I just get the blinking cursor. Maybe anyone has an idea?
